# Replace embedding layer in Keras model while keeping the rest of the architecture and weights intact

Tags: keras, word2vec, embedding, pre-trained-model

I have created a Keras Sequential Neural Network for sentiment analysis on twitter data, with the help of gensim word2vec library. I am creating an embedding dictionary by training the word2vec model on a larger tweet text corpus and then using the embeddings in a Keras Embedding layer. This works as it should.

Although, to run the model several times on a randomized dataset and to receive a more robust result, I would like to pretrain the model on other data. From this pretraining I want to save the architecture and the weights of the model, but with a new embedding layer fitted on this new dataset.

**In short: How do I load a pretrained Keras model with architecture and weights, and then replace the embedding layer with a new embedding layer/embedding matrix created on a new dataset?**

This is how the model is created:

```
`from tensorflow import keras`
`from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer`
`from keras.utils import pad_sequences`
`from keras.models import Sequential`
`from keras import layers`

`maxlen= 100`
`EMBEDDING_DIM = 100`
`embedding_layer = layers.Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                                EMBEDDING_DIM,
                                weights=[embedding_matrix],
                                input_length=maxlen,
                                trainable=True)`
`model = Sequential()`
`model.add(embedding_layer)`
`model.add(layers.Flatten())`
`model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))`
`model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))`
`model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])`
```

I've tried to load the pretrained model like this:

```
`pretrained_model = keras.models.load_model("my_model")`
`weights = pretrained_model.get_weights()`
`model.set_weights(weights)`
```

But I am having trouble with the number of weights in each layer. The number of weights in the loaded model and the new model does not correspond, even though they are created in the same manner. The only difference is the Embedding layer.

**I am not sure if the save and load function creates the miss-match or if the problem lies with the word2vec embedding dictionary. The Embeddings are created with the same vocab size.**

This is how the Embedding matrix is created:

```
`model = Word2Vec(sentences=texts, max_final_vocab=1000)`


`tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size)`
`tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df.iloc[:,7])`
`tokenized = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df.iloc[:,7])`
`word_index = tokenizer.word_index`

`EMBEDDING_DIM = 100`
`embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM))`
`for word, i in word_index.items():`
`  embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)`
`    if embedding_vector is not None:`
`      embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector`
```